# Recharts - pass array of values to Line component

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I have an array of values like this:
`array = [0, 0, 1, 2, 454, 3]`

How can i pass the array to Recharts Line component? Values should appear on y axis and index on x axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation states ([link](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/Line#points)):

> #### points
>
> The coordinates of all the points in the line, usually calculated internally.
>
> <sub>**FORMAT:**</sub>
>
> ```
> [{x: 12, y: 12, value: 240}]
> ```

To pass the array you've provided you need to transform the array a bit. You can do this with:

```
const data = array.map(x => ({pv: x}));

return (
  <LineChart data={data}>
    <Line type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#8884d8" />
  </LineChart>
);
```

Obviously left out a lot of things here, but you can probably leave the coordinates themselves out since you are likely drawing on a Cartesian plane. The coordinates will be calculated automatically - just pass the values.

Here, the line will select the `pv` key from your dataset, and draw them.

Snippet derived from: http://recharts.org/en-US/api/LineChart

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who want to use the data array as is, without array map function.
Providing a function to `dataKey` prop is your answer:

```
    const data= [0, 0, 1, 2, 454, 3];

    <LineChart width={500} height={300} data={data}>
      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
      <YAxis dataKey={(v) => v} />
      <Line type="monotone" dataKey={v=>v} stroke="#8884d8" />
    </LineChart>
```

In case you want to provide more data such as XAxis tick names, tooltip legend, you should  use the map function and add other properties.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an array of objects as data

```
const array = [0, 0, 1, 2, 454, 3];
const data = array.map((value,index)=>({index,value}))
```

and then

```
<LineChart width={600} height={300} data={data}>
   <XAxis dataKey="index"/>
   <YAxis/>
   <Line  dataKey="value" stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{r: 8}}/>
</LineChart>
```

Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/mxgkwszq/1/

Comment: Grazie Gabrierle, avevo già confermato l'altra risposta.